# How to know how many pattern segments are in the array?

Tags: c, arrays, function, definition, sub-array

So basically my problem is: 
I receive an array of ints and an array with an ints pattern to look for.
I need to return how many pattern segments are in the 1st array.

For example:

```
v=[5,  2,  2,  3,  4,  4,  4,  4,  1,  1, 2, 2] 
p=[2, 2]
```

this needs to return something like "there's 2 segments of p in v."

I've tried this but i don´t think it's the right method:

```c
int main()
{
   int v[] ={5,  2,  2,  3,  4,  4,  4,  4,  1,  1, 2, 2};
   int p[] ={2,2};
   int sizev, sizep;
   printf("%d", count_segments_repeated_ints(v,sizev,p,sizep));
   return 0;
}


int count_segments_repeated_ints(int v[], int sizev, int p[], int sizep){

    int i,j, ocr=0;
    //sizeof
    for(i=0; i < sizev; i++){
        for(j=0; j < sizep; j++){
            if(v[i]==p[j] && v[i+1]==p[j+1]){
                ocr++;
            }
        }
        return ocr;
    }
}
```

Comment: How many `p`s in `{1, 2, 2, 2, 3}`?

Comment: Use `int sizev = sizeof(v) / sizeof(v[0]);`. Better use type `size_t` instead of `int`, i.e. `size_t sizev = sizeof(v) / sizeof(v[0]);`. Use the same type for `count_segments_repeated_ints`'s arguments.

Comment: @pmg if we consider that p is an static array and stays always like that, i presume that the answer would be 2. if p its redimensional and not specif to those 2 numbers, it depends.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure that the same element of `v` can belong to different segments ... the problem could as well forbid that and your example wasn't specific enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit different solution is to just use a single loop and check for equality and increment the `j`-indexer while numbers match. If the `j`-indexer becomes greater or equal to `sizep` then there is a match hence increment `ocr`. Otherwise start from 0 again.

```
int i, j = 0, ocr = 0;

if (sizep > sizev) return 0;

for (i = 0; i < sizev; i++)
{
  if (v[i] == p[j]) j++;
  else
  {
    if (j > 0) i--;
    j = 0;
  }

  if (j >= sizep)
  {
    ocr++;
    j = 0;
    // If overlapping segments are allowed uncomment the following line:
    // i -= sizep - 1;
  }
}

return ocr;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to stop the outer loop before `sizev - sizep`, so you don't access outside the `v` array.

Second, your inner loop is incrementing `ocr` for each matching character. It should only increment it if *all* of the characters match. And you only need to compare `v[i+j]` with `p[j]`.

Third, `return ocr;` shouldn't be inside the loop.

```
int count_segments_repeated_ints(int v[], int sizev, int p[], int sizep){

    int i,j, ocr=0;
    for(i=0; i < sizev-sizep; i++){
        for(j=0; j < sizep; j++){
            int all_match = 1;
            if(v[i+j] != p[j]){
                all_match = 0;
                break;
            }
        }
        ocr += all_match;
    }
    return ocr;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters in your program variables `sizev` and `sizep` are not initialized.

In general `sizep` can be greater than `sizev` or even can be equal to `0` within the function.

This loop due to the enclosed if statement

```
    for(j=0; j < sizep; j++){
        if(v[i]==p[j] && v[i+1]==p[j+1]){
            ocr++;
        }
```

invokes undefined behavior because the value of the index in this expression `p[j+1]` can point outside the array. And moreover the array with a pattern can contain more elements than just two elements.

The function can be defined the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program. I renamed the function because this name `count_segments_repeated_ints` does not correspond to the assignment.

```
#include <stdio.h>

size_t count_sub_arrays( const int a1[], size_t n1, const int a2[], size_t n2 )
{
    size_t count = 0;

    if ( !( n1 < n2 ) && n2 != 0 )
    {
        for ( size_t i = 0, n = n1 - n2; i <= n; )
        {
            while ( i <= n && a1[i] != a2[0] ) ++i;

            if ( !( n < i ) )
            {
                size_t j = 1;

                while ( j < n2 && a1[i + j] == a2[j] ) j++;

                if ( j == n2 )
                {
                    ++count;
                    i += n2;
                }
                else
                {
                    ++i;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return count;
}

int main(void) 
{
   int a1[] = { 5,  2,  2,  3,  4,  4,  4,  4,  1,  1, 2, 2 };
   int a2[] = { 2, 2 }; 
   const size_t N1 = sizeof( a1 ) / sizeof( *a1 );
   const size_t N2 = sizeof( a2 ) / sizeof( *a2 );


   printf( "%zu\n", count_sub_arrays( a1, N1, a2, N2 ) );

   return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
2
```